# behaviour of visual studio web deploy publishing packages

Tags: package, visual-studio-2012, publishing, msdeploy, webdeploy

I have been doing some work recently with publishing mvc applications on visual studio 2012. I have been using publish profiles to configure web deploy to different environments. I have also been using web transforms to transform my web.config as per each of my publish profiles.

In a package, is there a setting to ensure the server its getting installed on wipes previous installed content from the previous install?

As an aside from the above, is it possible to package an application and not have it perform the transforms until gets deployed? Therefore the package is independent of the target server (dev, qa) and can installed on either.

Answer (score 0):

You [can deploy an existing package using publish profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683243/deploying-an-existing-package-using-publish-profiles) with some custom MSDeploy magic. However, I've not tried to hold onto web.config transforms and gone with MSDeploy parameters completely. It's worth attempting, but I've not tested my custom script with them so there may be some targets that I've forgotten.

I still use web.config transforms, but only to remove non-debug elements when creating the package (with a `Release` transform)