# How to share parameters configuration between VS publish profile and MSDeploy SetParameters.xml?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

I have a web application in Visual Studio 2012. I publish this website to IIS using publish profiles (.pubxml).

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>server</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>site</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>False</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName>domain\username</UserName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <MSDeployParameterValue Include="MyParam">
      <ParameterValue>MyValue</ParameterValue>
    </MSDeployParameterValue>
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Beside I setup a CI to build a package with msbuild and then use it to publish to the different environnement using msdeploy. Both in 2 separates steps, so I can reuse the same package multiple times.
To do this I need to use a SetParameters.xml with a different syntax than the publish profil used by VS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="site" />
  <setParameter name="MyParam" value="MyValue" />
  ...
</parameters>
```

Is there a way to share the parameters configuration in a single file so I can maintain only one file ?
I see [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683243/deploying-an-existing-package-using-publish-profiles) from 2014 but I can't managed to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've researched this and can't find a way to override the SetParameters file when publish via VisualStudio.  It doesn't look like the MSBuild tasks support this.

The best alternative I can offer is to use the commandline instead of right click publish.  You can create the MSDeploy package by calling the Package target:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild /t:Package /p:PublishProfile=<profile-name>
```

And then deploy using MSDeploy.exe:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package=WebApplication7.zip -dest:manifest=WebApplication7.DestManifest.xml -setParamFile:SetParameters.custom.xml
```

The following blog posts has more details:

https://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/25/the-anatomy-of-a-webdeploy-package/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is the way I deploy my packages with the CI. My question is to find a smart way to merge this solution with the clic once publish integrated in VS to allow both deployments with less configuration files.